# Como abrir windows update via codigo

Tags: c#, windows

Estou tendo alguns problemas com atualizações do windows, pois nem todos do trabalho sabem abrir o windows update para olhar.
Então queria desenvolver um executavel que eles possam abrir com um duplo click por exemplo.

Eu testei usando C# e cheguei no seguinte codigo:

```
bool result = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:windowsupdate"));
```

Porem, não consigo executar o arquivo do codigo.
Pensei em executar via .bat mas não sei qual a sintexe pra abrir um C# no cmd.

Comment: isso pode ser feito muito mais facilmente pela administração da rede, é possível ativer o update automático, "forçar" os computadores a fazer uma atualização, etc, não seria mais prático e seguro fazer isso?

Comment: Testei este código em um projeto UWP e funcionou perfeitamente